# Column with datatype TEXT or Varchchar returning null in json even its not

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a php-file that returns a JSON-array

---

```
NAME          TYPE            COLLATION               NULL
title         varchar(50)    latin1_swedish_ci       No
description   text            latin1_swedish_ci       No
```

**description** field returns null even it has data in it

---

Json:

```
{
"pd_main": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Attire",
        "description": null,
        "time_stamp": "2016-09-03 01:35:55",
        "cat": "sa",
        "sub_cat": "sa",
        "image": "sa",
        "icon": "sa"
    }
  ]
  }
```

php file

```
$sql = "select * from pd"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 { 
  $resul[] = $row;

  }  
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode(array("pd_main"=>$resul));
```

---

If i reduce the conten in decription then it appears in json, but i want large text

Comment: Have you tried doing `var_dump($resul);`?

Comment: Yes, it returns content from table ["description"]=> string(459) "What you wear also contribute

Comment: But does not show in my json ..what to do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function json_last_error_msg() to check whether there is any error or not.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: I have ever faced the same issue with you. I used mb_convert_encoding() function to convert the data.